# R ggplot2 how to draw times on y upside down

Tags: r, ggplot2

using basicly the code from [Time series visualization for start, end, duration in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310163/time-series-visualization-for-start-end-duration-in-r/10312045#10312045)

```
date = c("2011-11-15", "2011-11-16", "2011-11-17", "2011-11-19")
start = c("12:01:27", "12:01:25", "12:01:02", "12:01:12")
end = c("12:30:15", "12:32:15", "12:39:12", "12:30:18")
df = data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(date),
     ystart = as.POSIXct(start, format="%H:%M:%S"), 
     yend = as.POSIXct(end, format="%H:%M:%S"),
     xstart=as.POSIXct(paste(date, "12:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
     xend = as.POSIXct(paste(date, "14:00:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ggplot() + geom_rect(data=df, aes(ymin=ystart, ymax=yend, xmin=xend, xmax=xstart))
```

I get almost the plot I want to have, but in the example it's upsidedown, how can I reverse the y axis? It should start with the mornings on top, and draw the nights at bottom.

Edit: The question is not a duplicate, its related but not the same. I tried the other method, but it did not work (see below in comments). I am not sure why, but I suspect that it's because I use geom_rect instead of geom_point, and the scale is discrete instead of continuos, also the datatype seems different. Could somebody please explain how to use the other method with my example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626186/4550695

Comment: @MikkoMarttila : it didnt work (or at least I was not able to put them together as needed), I tried to change my data, but got Errors like "Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only" and others, i guess scale_y_continuous is a problem, and also that I need to use geom_rect not geom_point

Comment: It seems that the linked answer has been broken by a recent release of **ggplot**, but it's simple to fix. I can't post an answer as the question is closed, but see if this explanation helps: https://gist.github.com/mikmart/bfbf62839fbdd162b4b88e6d43e0c858.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila : Thanks a lot! Your code seems to work, I'll try with my data later and post an update when I am done.